# Why the request is not done?

Tags: angular, mean-stack, mean

The component call to the method getCityCoords() but it never ends.

It retrieves some objects with geographical and weather information, if there only a few objects it works, and I have 200 code, but if there are more, it never ends.

[image]

What I have investigated indicates that there are a problem with the connection, some stuff about TCP, but I don´t know how to solve that. There´s some way to close the connections?

This is the code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MapService } from '../../services/map.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Map } from '../../models/map';

import { Icon, icon, Marker, marker } from 'leaflet';

declare let L;
var map;

@Component({
  selector: 'map-component',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  private defaultIcon: Icon = icon({
    iconUrl: 'assets/leaflet/marker-icon.png',
    shadowUrl: 'assets/leaflet/marker-shadow.png',
    iconSize: [41, 51], // => random values you have to choose right ones for your case
    iconAnchor: [20, 51] // => random values too
  });

  public coordinates: [number];
  constructor(
    private _mapService: MapService, private _router: Router
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2); L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    this.getLocations();
  }

  getLocations() {

    var geoJsonMulti = {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [

      ]
    }

    this._mapService.getCoordinates().subscribe(
      response => {
        if (!response) {
          this._router.navigate(['/']);
        } else {
          var layer = response.cityFeatures.cities;
          layer.forEach(layer => {
            geoJsonMulti.geometries.push(layer);
          })
        }
        var myStyle = {
          "color": "#ff7800",
          "weight": 5,
          "opacity": 0.65
        };
        L.geoJSON(geoJsonMulti, {
          style: myStyle
        }).addTo(map);

        var myIcon = L.icon({
          iconUrl: 'assets/leaflet/marker-icon.png',
          iconSize: [41, 51],
          iconAnchor: [20, 51],
          popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
          shadowUrl: 'assets/leaflet/marker-shadow.png',
          shadowSize: [68, 95],
          shadowAnchor: [22, 94]
        });

        var options={

        }


        for(let i=0;i<geoJsonMulti.geometries.length;i++){
          var arrayCoords=[geoJsonMulti.geometries[i].coordinates[1],geoJsonMulti.geometries[i].coordinates[0]]
          var marker=L.marker(arrayCoords, {icon: myIcon,clickable: false}).addTo(map).bindPopup("<b>Average temp: </b>"+geoJsonMulti.geometries[i].averageTemp+
          "</br> <b>Average precipitations: </b>"+geoJsonMulti.geometries[i].averageRain);
        }


      },

      error => {
        let errorMessage = <any>error;
        if (errorMessage !== null) {
          let body = JSON.parse(error._body);
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There´s some way to close the connections?

Sure. Unsubscribing cancels the request, I believe. For example, something like this:

```
const LONG_ENOUGH_ALREADY = 120000; // milliseconds

this._mapService.getCoordinates()
   .pipe(
      takeUntil(timer(LONG_ENOUGH_ALREADY))
   .subscribe( // the rest
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn´t work, the undone request it's still made. I have added a screenshot

Comment: Depends what constitutes "long enough". Try with `LONG_ENOUGH_ALREADY = 1000`

Comment: Now the connection is "cancelled"

Comment: Well, what else can we do from the front end? We can either wait until the request returns some data, or we can cancel it.

Comment: That´s weird because the back end returns an objetc with objects inside, if the main object has only two or three objects, it works, if there are more, the request dones not finish